# Unable to get Clickable button in UI Automator Viewer

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am trying to automate clickable button for a react-native based Application. I was stopped getting clickable button as in UI Automator Viewer displaying clickable button status FALSE. So, can you suggest me any other alternative way to automate the clickable action using Appium.

Using Selenium 3.5.3 version, Appium for Windows 1_4_16_1.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRGlA.png)
[image]

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6XXt.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First: start using [appium-desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases) and not an old appium server 1.4.16, but 1.7.x

Second: ReactNative app is interpreted as **Native application**, so you need to use **Appium** on client side, not Selenium

Final: In appium-desktop you can directly try to click your button to see if it works.